# JS split string on positive lookahead, avoid overlapping cases

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a set of data that includes dated notes, all concatenated, as in the example below.  Assume the date always comes at the beginning of its note.  I'd like to split these into individual notes.  I've used a positive lookahead so I can keep the delimiter (the date).

Here's what I'm doing:

```
  const notes = "[3/28- A note. 3/25- Another note. 3/24- More text. 10/19- further notes. [10/18- Some more text.]"
  const pattern = /(?=\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}[- ]+)/g
  console.log(notes.split(pattern))
```

and the result is

```
[ '[',
  '3/28- A note. ',
  '3/25- Another note. ',
  '3/24- More text. ',
  '1',
  '0/19- further notes. [',
  '1',
  '0/18- Some more text.]' ]
```

The pattern `\d{1,2}` matches both `10/19` and `0/19` so it splits before both of those.
Instead I'd like to have

```
[ '[',
  '3/28- A note. ',
  '3/25- Another note. ',
  '3/24- More text. ',
  '10/19- further notes. [',
  '10/18- Some more text.]' ]
```

(I can handle the extraneous brackets later.)

How can I accomplish this split with regex or any other technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your wanted output, you can prepend a word boundary in the lookahead, and you can omit the plus sign at the end of the pattern.

```
(?=\b\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}[- ])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yi73Vn/1)

```js
const notes = "[3/28- A note. 3/25- Another note. 3/24- More text. 10/19- further notes. [10/18- Some more text.]"
const pattern = /(?=\b\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}[- ])/g
console.log(notes.split(pattern))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid `split()` here and instead use `match()`:

```js
var notes = "[3/28- A note. 3/25- Another note. 3/24- More text. 10/19- further notes. [10/18- Some more text.]";
var matches = notes.match(/\[?\d+\/\d+\s*-\s*.*?\.\]?/g);
console.log(matches);
```

You may do a further cleanup of leading/trailing brackets using regex, e.g.

```js
var input = "[10/18- Some more text.]";
var output = input.replace(/^\[|\]$/, "");
```

Comment: Thanks, this works on my example but not on longer notes that involve multiple sentences on one date, or the user didn't use a period, e.g. "[3/28- A note. With more details. 10/7 i hate punctuation 11/9 Last note."  The issue with `match` is that I don't have a way to guarantee where the note will end, other than detecting the next date.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.replaceAll()` and this regex:

```
/(\[?\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\-.+?)/
// Replacement
"\n$1"
```

**Figure I** - Regex

| Segment | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `(\[?` | Begin capture group - match literal "[" zero or one time |
| `\d{1,2}\/` | match a digit one or two times and a literal "/" |
| `\d{1,2}\-` | match a digit one or two times and a literal "-" |
| `.+?)` | match anything one to any number of times "lazily" - end capture group |

**Figure II** - Replacement

| Segment | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `\n` | New line |
| `$1` | Everything matched in the capture group `(`...`)` |

```js
const notes = "[3/28- A note. 3/25- Another note 3/24- More text. 10/19- further notes [10/18- Some more text.]";
const rgx = new RegExp(/(\[?\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\-.+?)/, 'g');
let result = notes.replaceAll(rgx, "\n$1");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, see my comment on Tim Biegeleisen's answer: your regex works on my simple example but not if the user left out periods.

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtLee answer is updated. You should update your question with the new criteria.